# SQL Search does not start in SSMS 18.5

Tags: ssms, redgate

I have updated SSMS to v18.5 and then uninstall SQL Search, downloaded the latest one and installed. 
SSMS started, I click button "SQL Search" - no any errors/exceptions but SQL Search does not start.
I have repeated these actions on 2 workstations W7 and W10. The same result.
How to fix it?

Comment: Is there anything in the log file (`%localappdata%\Red Gate\Logs\SQLSearch 3`) that might show what the problem is?

Comment: Having the same issue, just updated ssms to 18.5 and SQL search won't open. Nothing in the logs as well.

Comment: Because this is top on Google: if in someone's case, it DOES start but is greyed out, disconnect object explorer and then reconnect to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSMS 18.10 + latest SQLSearch - work fine.

Answer (score 33):

Ok there is some issue with SQL Search version 3.0, but when I tried SQL Search version 3.5 it is working fine. Download it from here: [v3.5.2.2607](https://download.red-gate.com/checkforupdates/SQLSearch/SQLSearch_3.5.2.2607.exe)

More details [here](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/86736/sql-search-3-4-2-2567-not-working-with-ssms-18-5)

Newer versions of SQL Search are [listed here](https://download.red-gate.com/checkforupdates/SQLSearch/).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the default download page points still to version 3.4. https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/installer/

Comment: 3.5 works for me too. Not sure why the download from RedGate is 3.4 though.

Comment: Still broken as of 9/9/2020. 3.5 working it appears.

Comment: Try removing and install this exact version: v3.5.2.2607

Comment: I think @SQLJax is trying to say that the default download from the Redgate site is still 3.4x and broken. I am surprised that they haven't updated it yet.

Comment: Got it... Yes, it's surprising they have not yet updated even though they know and replied to a similar issue on their own forums.

Comment: @Shekar Thank you. That was what I was trying to get across.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install this version : https://download.red-gate.com/checkforupdates/SQLSearch/SQLSearch_3.5.0.2590.exe

It works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue in SQL Search 3.5.5.2703

The [Redgate Forums](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/88476/sql-search-boxes-are-grayed-out) have this workaround which worked for me:

> I think you are running into an issue we are aware of and working on.
> Apologies for the hassle! As a workaround, could I ask you to try the
> following?
>
> - disconnect your SQL server from SSMS Object explorer
> - Close and reopen SQL Search
> - Reconnect your SQL Server